# How to Bulk Insert Related Records?

Tags: data-loader, data-import-wizard

I have a request from a client to add Multiple Contact related records to an Account.

I have a CSV with Account Records IDs and Contact Records IDs. But I'm unsure on how to bulk insert related contacts records to an Account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import to the Account Contact Relationship object, see the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.account_contact_relationship_fields.htm&type=5).